# ORA-01031: insufficient privileges -- package procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

In oracle, when I execute my package, I get error :

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

My users have dba admin role.

myPackage in the mySchema. But table different in schema.

I tried below script but not solve my problem.

```
grant execute on mySchema.myPackage to otherSchema;
```

Thanks for interest.

```
execute
mySchema.myPackage.disabledTableConstraint(otherSchema.table_Cons);
```

Comment: Its not only about granting the privilege to package. You need to see if the `procedure` you are using from `package` has any schema object which require explicit permission.

Comment: PL/SQL does not use roles (unless you compile it with invoker rights, which is a rather specialised option and not recommended for normal code), so whatever DBA admin role the package owner has does not exist at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Privileges granted via roles don't really matter in PL/SQL. By default, packages execute with definer's rights, which means they execute with the privileges of the owning schema.

It looks like `mySchema` is trying to disable a constraint in `otherSchema`, so this is basically as if you were logged in as `mySchema` and trying to do:

```
alter table otherSchema.someTable disable constraint myconstraint;
```

It sounds like `mySchema` doesn't have privileges to do that to `otherSchema`. You can:

1. Grant the `ALTER TABLE` privilege from `otherSchema` to `mySchema`. You'd have to do this on a table-by-table basis.
2. Grant the `ALTER ANY TABLE` system privilege to `mySchema`. This may be dangerous.
3. Make the procedure invoker's rights with the `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` clause. This will make the procedure run with the privileges of the schema calling it, in this case, `otherSchema`.

See: [Managing Security for Definer's Rights and Invoker's Rights](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG658)

Comment: I tried second option. Either otherschema or mySchema have alter any table privilege. But not working.